# How to convert a string into ASCII?

Tags: python, ascii

How can I convert a string, say `"HELLO"`, into something like this?

As ASCII string: `"72_69_76_76_79"`.

I tried `[ord(c) for c in string]`, but it returns a list.

I want the result in the form of string

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:

```
"_".join([str(ord(c)) for c in "HELLO"])
```